# Mac Pro won't reboot

Tags: mac, reboot, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro, a couple years old now, that is having trouble rebooting.

On a consistent basis after the OS has shut down and the machine is restarting, I get the familiar chime, but nothing more. Then, I can hear something clicking inside the tower which sounds like it's coming from the DVD reader (which is empty).

I have to hold down the power button to shut everything down, at which point I can turn the computer on again no problem.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before? Any tips/tricks on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try resetting the PRAM with the directions here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379

It usually fixes really odd unexplainable problems.